# How to enter data automatically when Excel is minimized?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office, barcode-scanner

I am entering each Barcode data to an Excel File. But I want to keep the excel file minimized and data coming from Barcode reader automatically enter in that minimized Excel sheet. Is that possible using VBA Code or using any other method? I have tried some methods but didn't get what I need. So can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

I have tried this code to set the file Active.

```
Sub test() 
Dim wbName As Window 
Set wbName = ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1)
'You can use Windows("[Workbook Name]") as well 
wbName.Visible = False 
wbName.Visible = True 
End Sub
```

But this is not I need. I need automatically enter barcode details to Excel file when it is minimized.

Comment: It is entirely possible to do that using VBA. Can you show us what you have tried so far? And more specifically, out of what application are you running the code? OUt of another Excel Workbook or something else?

Comment: @rohrl77 I am working on Excel file sir. And I am not much knowledgable in VBA. I have tried this 

Sub test()

    Dim wbName As Window

    Set wbName = ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1)'You can use Windows("[Workbook Name]") as well

    wbName.Visible = False
    wbName.Visible = True

End Sub

Comment: Can you guide me how to accomplish this? I really appreciate that sir.

Comment: What i know is Bar-code entry is like a keyboard entry, the cell has to be selected in order to enter data in it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use 'ActiveWorkbook', but refer to the workbook with its actual name.
Something like

```
sub test()

dim wb as workbook
set wb = Workbooks("Book1.xslx")

'insert code

end sub
```

difficult to explain further as we don't have any reference on what you've tried so far.

Comment: I need to insert barcode data when user showing his id card to the barcode scanner. Even Excel file is minimized I need to enter those barcode details automatically?

Comment: I think it would be best if you'd copied an example of your data AND part of the code you already have. Without a single viewing of your basic problem (made anonymous if required) we can hardly search for a solution.